# Why scipy and Excel generate slightly different p-value for two-sample t-test?

Tags: python, excel, scipy, t-test

For `python`, it is [two-side test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) by default:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
wt = np.array([71.93636,71.34689,72.2162])
mut = np.array([71.58995,70.82698,70.89562])
t, p = stats.ttest_ind(wt, mut, equal_var=False)
print(t,p)
```

I got

```
2.06163943002 0.108425721876
```

In `Excel`, `Data` tab - `Data Analysis` - `t-Test: Two-Sample Assuming Unequal Variances`, I got same value for `t`, but slightly different value for `p` (0.1084... vs 0.1082...)

Can I ask why?

[image]

Comment: I guess if you go read those function definitions, you will discover that parameters have different meaning or introduce some extra factors in computations. Check if there are one or two-sided testes. Go to the source, you will likely find out why.

Comment: Or maybe it is implementation dependent, or due to numerical stability among algorithms.

Comment: If you use `equal_var=True` in your call to `stats.ttest_ind()`, the p value matches the one in Excel.  Where does the formula that you used in Excel come from?  You haven't shown us the Excel code; all we see is the numbers.

Comment: Did you use [`T.TEST`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/T-TEST-function-D4E08EC3-C545-485F-962E-276F7CBED055)?  If so, what value did you use for the `Type` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
from scipy import stats
stats.ttest_rel(wt,mut)
```

it should match the same calculations in Excel.

`rel` is for related samples and `ind` is for independent samples.

Comment: thanks, but what is the difference between `stats.ttest_rel` and `stats.ttest_ind`?

Comment: Edited my answer to give the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The methods IN excel is 「Two-Sample Assuming Unequal Variances」 and it should match the result genernae from

```
st.ttest_ind(sample_1, sample_2, equal_var = False, alternative = 'less')
```

and It's not.

I got the same confusion with post stater.

Comment: Improve the formatting and the explanation of the post

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34516267)